# Login loop 16.04

Tags: login

I'm not expecting much as I've searched the and tried a whole bunch of stuff, but any help would be appreciated. Running 16.04 until I hit the login loop. I tried recovery modes and tty logins everything I could find. I resorted to installing 16.04 on a new partition just so I could get back on the system. I have additional accounts on the downed system but all of them are locked out. I tried restoring the .Xauthority and other authentication files. Not using any nvidia drivers: Kernel driver in use: i915. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Sorry but I am new to Ubuntu and if I knew what exactly I should be looking for I would have included that info. I have zero access to an Ubuntu install, either thru the GUI or thru the command line. All I get back from my login attempts in the tty is: "Invalid password" Part of my confusion is that I had to install Ubuntu onto a new partition just to get any access to the computer. Probably was a better way but it was all I could come up with. Now that I am on the new partition on the new Ubuntu install I am not sure I am looking at the correct info on the correct partition. So when you ask for the output of "ls -ld" how do I run that for the downed system and not the one I am currently using? Thanks for helping me define my question better (or maybe I made it worse)

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you include potentially useful information such as *what happened* when you tried tty login, *what are the results of* `ls -ld` for your home directory and  .Xauthority file, any error messages from your `.xsession-errors` file

Comment: What happens in recovery mode?